# For condition if a string variable equals a special character "&#10004"

Tags: javascript, html

so i'm trying to check if an innerHTML character using javascript has the character &#10004 (which is a tick symbol). If check a normal string it works fine like this:

```
if (requiredField == "Valid")
```

However if i want to check if the innerHTML is the tick symbol what can i do? I have tried

```
if (requiredField == "&#10004")
```

This is not working, hopefully there is an easy way to do this.

Regards,
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are expecting to compare it with `tick` symbol then why don't you compare with the `tick` directly using `innerHTML` or `innerText`. It will consider that as a `tick` and give you exactly what has been rendered on the page which is `✔`. So, better to use that for special symbols:

```js
var requiredField = document.getElementById('requiredFied').innerText;
if (requiredField == "✔"){
  console.log('correct');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='requiredFied'>&#10004;</div>
```

Comment: @Slacky88 glad to help